# SQL Database Design Union Data Type?

Tags: sql, join, database-design, union

This may be a basic question, but I'm curious about what the most reasonable "preferred" way to design a database with a union type is.

What I mean is consider a table `Post` which has only 1 piece of attached content and the attached content can be of type `video`, `audio`, `pdf`, `text` or whatever.  The normalized way would be create a table for each of these content types. But there needs to be a connecting table to query all of the other tables `type` field indicating the type of content.

That means each of these need to be queried when the initial table is queried.

Another way of handling this is having a kitchen sink `content` table with a type field on it.

I ask because I'm not particularly versed in database design.  I'm curious what a normal pattern would be for data structured this way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of "one-of" modeling is tricky.  Some databases have built-in support for such functionality, such as inheritance.

One method is to have an `attachments` table and to combine all into one table.  This would have columns such as:

- `attachments_id`
- `type check type in ('video', 'audio', . . .)`
- columns needed for any of them.

More commonly, each of these would be a separate entity, because the columns describing them would be quite different -- and often have their own relationships.  In this case, a simple method for a handful of types is a separate column for each one, along with a constraint that at most one is not `NULL`:

```
check ( (case when video_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when audio_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        . . .  <= 1
      )
```

This allows properly declared foreign key relationships.

Another method is a variation on this.  Assuming that all the id columns have the same type, then use the columns:

```
attachment_type varchar(255) check (attachment_type in ('video', 'audio', . . .),
attachment_id int
```

The type would determine the type of `id`, but the database would not validate this.

And another method is a more complex inheritance pattern, which involves setting up individual tables for each entity, along with a type in each one.  And then setting up an `attachments` table.  This looks like:

```
attachments_id int generated always as identity primary key,
attachment_type varchar(255) check (attachment_type in ('video', 'audio', . . .),
unique (type, attachments_id)
```

And then:

```
video_id int primary key,
type varchar(255) generated always as
foreign key video_id references (type, attachments_id)
```

and so on for the other tables.  This sets up a foreign key relationship to `attachments` and makes sure that the types match.